# The ICS tag has a tag wiki describing the iCal file format, but is mostly used on android "Ice Cream Sandwich" questions. How to fix?

Tags: support, tag-wiki

[ics](/questions/tagged/ics) has a tag wiki describing the iCal file format.  The tag is mostly used on android questions (as an acronym of [Ice Cream Sandwich](http://www.android.com/about/ice-cream-sandwich/)).

What's the best thing to do with this?

Can I just change the tag wiki to describe Ice Cream Sandwich?  Should I also untag the actual iCal questions and leave them tagged [ical](/questions/tagged/ical)?

EDIT:  The other option suggested in the comments is to change the tag on all the android questions. This has now been done by AakashM.  Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure? It could be that people have been applying the wrong tag and that a new [tag:ice-cream-sandwich] tag is needed instead.

Comment: I've been busy on [tag:ics] and I think there are no longer any [tag:ice-cream-sandwich]-related questions on it, but I'm sure to have missed some

Comment: [ICS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Connection_Sharing)? I think that tag is ambiguous and needs to be renamed to reflect its relation to iCal.

Comment: I agree with @ChrisF. The ICS tag should be co-opted for iCal. [tag:ice-cream-sandwich] can be used for Android's 4.0 platform (and should probably be synonymized with [tag:android-4.0].

Comment: I looked at the link to Ice Cream Sandwich that you provided, and **nowhere did I see that the official abbreviation for Ice Cream Sandwich is ICM**. Just because *you* use that acronym as an abbreviation does not provide sufficient cause to go changing tag wikis and coopting a tag reasonably used for iCal or Internet Connection Sharing.

Comment: @CodyGray I don't use that acronym myself, but it was apparent that many other people were.  I clicked on the tag, and noticed all the questions were about android, and the wiki was about ical.  It's no longer a problem since AakashM has been through and retagged the android questions to ice-cream-sandwich, so I'll vote to close my question.

Comment: I've gone through and retagged the questions incorrectly tagged [ics] to [ice-cream-sandwich] (or at least, all those in the [android] tag as well). there's probably a few where people didn't tag with android.

Answer (score 2):

The best way of addressing this is to retag all the android questions [ice-cream-sandwich](/questions/tagged/ice-cream-sandwich).  This was recommended by ChrisF and Robert Harvey in the comments and implemented by AakashM - thanks everyone.