# Three tags used for 2 topics: [ics], [ice-cream-sandwich] and [icalendar]

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

I noticed the [ice-cream-sandwich](/questions/tagged/ice-cream-sandwich) and the [ics](/questions/tagged/ics) tags. At first I supposed they were synonyms, but [ics](/questions/tagged/ics) is a synonym of [icalendar](/questions/tagged/icalendar) (according to their tag descriptions).
No problem so far, except that [ics](/questions/tagged/ics) is mostly used as a synonym for [ice-cream-sandwich](/questions/tagged/ice-cream-sandwich)...

A quick search showed similar meta-questions:

- [Mark iCalendar, ics, and ical tags as synonyms?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134822/mark-icalendar-ics-and-ical-tags-as-synonyms)
- [The ICS tag has a tag wiki describing the iCal file format, but is mostly used on android "Ice Cream Sandwich" questions. How to fix?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124981/the-ics-tag-has-a-tag-wiki-describing-the-ical-file-format-but-is-mostly-used-o)

Both questions are reasonable old and their solutions are lost already/again... So some firm/new action is required!

Personally, I think it would be best to keep [ice-cream-sandwich](/questions/tagged/ice-cream-sandwich) and [icalendar](/questions/tagged/icalendar) and forbid the use of [ics](/questions/tagged/ics). As this seems to result in the clearest situation.

But making [ics](/questions/tagged/ics) a synonym of one or the other, is also possible.

Note: In both cases, all [ics](/questions/tagged/ics) questions needs to be sorted out and added to the correct tag.

Comment: You should probably tag this as [meta-tag:tag-blacklist-request].

Answer (score 9):

I would personally vote that the [ics](/questions/tagged/ics) tag is removed and not marked as a synonym of either, it wouldn't be an ideal solution regardless of which is chosen as an overriding synonym as half of the questions would still end up tagged incorrectly.

I think the solution for now is to simply retag all of the erroneous [ics](/questions/tagged/ics) questions with [ice-cream-sandwich](/questions/tagged/ice-cream-sandwich), and then the [ics](/questions/tagged/ics) tag can stay as a synonym of [icalendar](/questions/tagged/icalendar) or be removed entirely, retagging the others as [icalendar](/questions/tagged/icalendar).

At present there are only **224** questions tagged with [ics](/questions/tagged/ics), and the [invalid ones are primarily also tagged with](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ics+android) [android](/questions/tagged/android) (50 questions) making them distinguishable. It shouldn't be that difficult a cleanup to perform manually, so I'm starting to do that now.

**Update**: I've retagged all of the questions with both [android](/questions/tagged/android) and [ics](/questions/tagged/ics) that needed it, and now going through the ones without that tag also. I've noticed that [ics](/questions/tagged/ics) is also used for `internet connection sharing`, although this doesn't have another tag (and shouldn't really need it as it belongs on SuperUser).

**Update #2**: All of the questions are now retagged as far as I can see. The `164` remaining questions tagged [ics](/questions/tagged/ics) are valid and related to `.ics` files or iCal in general.

Comment: +1 Nice work! But we still need to come to a consensus to prevent this in the future!

Comment: @Veger Definitely, but remember there's unfortunately no way to block a tag from being used entirely (see [tag:tips-and-tricks] and [tag:homework]). To be fair, there were only around 60 incorrect tags out of 224, so I'd say the issue isn't too great a problem at the moment.

Comment: @RudiVisser: The SE devs have a way to blacklist tags which become problems (consistently get recreated when they shouldn't exist, or have the potential to be recreated). As far as I'm aware, they can even apply this blacklist to tags which still exist. The [tag:ics] tag needs to be destroyed. We don't keep ambiguous tags, even as synonyms. It's only causing confusion so it shouldn't exist.